# Array in dialog checklist in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, dialog

my problem is that I have an array of packages but when I run my code not all packages are displayed.
And I want all Packages in one Column...

The PACKAGES array looks like this:

package1 package2 package3 package4 ... #There are 21 packages

```
exec 3>&1
MASCHINE_TEST=$( dialog --no-lines  --checklist  "Which Package do you want  
to choose?"  120 80 ${#PACKAGES[@]} \ "${PACKAGES[@]}" 2>&1 1>&3)
exec 3>&-
```

This is how the Output looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlHrv.png)

Please Help me!

Comment: quotes are missing around parameter to avoid word splititng : use `"${PACKAGES[@]}"` instead of `${PACKAGES[@]}` also to get the number of item in array `${#PACKAGES[@]}`, `${#PACKAGES}` is the length of first item

Comment: Thanks @NahuelFouilleul but it's still looks the same.

Comment: have you tried to change `${#PACKAGES}` by `${#PACKAGES[@]}` ?

Comment: Yeah I tried that too.

Comment: I suspect that I did something wrong with the description or the tag. But I can not find my mistake.